# NoClassDefFoundError-om/google/api/client/googleapis/batch/json/JsonBatchCallback

Tags: java

I have a static java project and have so  many class in it. used jar of java batch,drive Api , mongo Connnection etc and i have no errors compile time but while running a main class  i am getting this.what can i do for this ?

Error: Unable to initialize main class kioskdriveCollabMain
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent

Error: Unable to initialize main class kioskdriveCollabMain
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/googleapis/batch/json/JsonBatchCallback

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` causes when the dependency isn't resolved i.e. it is unable to find the specified class.

- `com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent` requires [google-http-java-client](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent.html) jar.
- `com/google/api/client/googleapis/batch/json/JsonBatchCallback` requires [google-api-java-client](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/batch/json/JsonBatchCallback.html) jar.